# How to properly align equations in widetext environment

Tags: equations, align, environments

How to align the equations inside the widetext
environment as given in the following code?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,float fix, prb, aps, showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,color}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{multirow,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom 
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
\begin{widetext}
\begin{align*}
&\left.
\begin{aligned}
\Big\langle\Phi_{\mathbf{K}}\Big|&=\Big(|0,X\rangle,0\Big), \quad\\ 
 \Big\langle\Phi_{\mathbf{K}}\Big|&=\Big(|0,X\rangle,0\Big), \quad\\
\vdots \\
 \Big\langle\Phi_{\mathbf{K}}\Big|&=\Big(|0,X\rangle,0\Big), \quad
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\begin{aligned}
    &\text{text text text text}\\
    &E_{\mathcal{N}=0}=E_{\mathcal{N}=0}= \dots=E_{\mathcal{N}=0}=0
\end{aligned}
\\
\begin{aligned}
\langle\Phi|= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big({-}|\mathcal{N},X\rangle,~|\mathcal{N}{-}J,X\rangle\big)\\
\langle\Phi|= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big({-}|\mathcal{N},X\rangle,~|\mathcal{N}{-}J,X\rangle\big)
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{widetext}
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom 
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place an alignment anchor `&` before the second `aligned`. I've made some minor other updates as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom 
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
\begin{widetext}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{align*}
  & \left.\begin{aligned}
      \bigl\langle \Phi_{\mathbf{K}} \bigm| &= \bigl( | 0, X \rangle, 0 \bigr), \quad \\ 
      \bigl\langle \Phi_{\mathbf{K}} \bigm| &= \bigl( | 0, X \rangle, 0 \bigr),       \\
                                            &\vdotswithin{=}                          \\
      \bigl\langle \Phi_{\mathbf{K}} \bigm| &= \bigl( | 0, X \rangle, 0 \bigr),
    \end{aligned}
    \right\}
    \begin{aligned}
      & \text{text text text text} \\
      & E_{\mathcal{N} = 0} = E_{\mathcal{N} = 0} = \dots = E_{\mathcal{N} = 0} = 0
    \end{aligned} \\
  & \kern\nulldelimiterspace\, \begin{aligned}
      \bigl\langle \Phi \bigm| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigl( {-}| \mathcal{N}, X \rangle, |\mathcal{N}{-}J, X \rangle \bigr) \\
      \bigl\langle \Phi \bigm| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \bigl( {-}| \mathcal{N}, X \rangle, |\mathcal{N}{-}J, X \rangle \bigr)
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{widetext}
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom 
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text
Random textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom textRandom text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! for the answer.